# Windows Azure: Missing Master Page after deployment

Tags: azure

I have an Azure application that I published to the staging environment. When I try to log into the application its throwing the below error. It works fine on my local environment. Do I need do anything different in the deployment?

```
Parser Error
```

Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: The file '/Views/Shared/Site2.Master' does not exist.

Source Error:

Line 1:  <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site2.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage" %>
Line 2:
Line 3:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose it is possible that your master page is not marked as 'content'.  However, that would seem unlikely at first.  To confirm it is being packaged, you can unzip and inspect the package (cspkg) before you deploy it to see if the file is in the package.  You do this by creating a system environment variable called '_CSPACK_FORCE_NOENCRYPT_' and setting that to true.  Once you do this, you can rename the cspkg to .zip and open with a normal unzipper.  There is another funny looking file in there (the biggest one usually) that you can rename to .zip again and it holds all your files.  Dig through that and confirm the file is there.

Comment: Thanks Dunnry! Can you expand on how to create the system environment variable?

Comment: From Start Menu:  Right click Computer > Properties, select 'Advanced System Settings' link from left hand pane.  Under 'Advanced' tab, click Environment Variables.  Under 'System Variables' create a new one with the settings.  Restart VS.NET.

Comment: Found the problem using your suggestion. The file was not included in the project. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: please explain how to include the file in the package